# NextJS Image - Remove white space around image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm having a problem with Next/image, I can't get my head around how the sizing works.

I'm trying to get the images without whitespace around them, but I want it to be responsive without hardcoded image sizes. I used a purple background color to make it clear what I'm trying to get rid of. For some reason the images always show up as a square.

I set the images to 100% width and height so that it takes the size of the parent Box, but it seems like the size of the Box doesn't make a difference. Can anyone explain to me how this works?

[image]

I used objectFit=contain so that it retains the correct aspect ratio. And I used layout=responsive for the variable image size.

```
{images.map((image, index) => (
    <Box key={index}>
        <Box sx={{ mb: 1, bgcolor: "purple" }}>
            {image.url.startsWith("http") && (
                <Image
                    src={image.url}
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    layout="responsive"
                    objectFit="contain"
                    alt="myimage"
                />
            )}
        </Box>
        {textfield and buttons}
    </Box>
))}
```

Comment: objectFit contain value gives those purple bars. This property makes whole image visible no matter of parent size.

Comment: @kuba is right. We make container div `relative` and just give `fill={true}`. This approach is best with Next/Image component imo.

Comment: @kuba If I remove objectFit the aspect ratio isn't correct anymore.

Comment: @Erenn Thanks I just tried surrounding image with Box, and making Box relative, and adding fill to image. However the ratio isn't correct anymore without objectFit.

Comment: After than play with image css properties. Sometimes we use `object-fit: contain/cover` too. You may need to crop/edit too. It seems like your images need update.